# How to filter with present and previous value in pandas dataframe and create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

'''Hi,

How to check when value in the column "ABM_0_8_11_dec" is 3 and its previous value is 4.
Then I would like to take 8 LSB of "ABM_0_8_11_dec" with 4 and combine it with 8 LSB of "ABM_0_8_11_dec" with 3 and put this row in a new dataframe.

Below is the code for dataframe. '''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Analysis_of_ARINC_Parameter.csv') 

# Convert both parameter ABM_0 and ABM_1 to Binary and also coonvert it to 16 digit binary
mask = 0b10000000000000000
df['ABM_0_Bin']=(np.bitwise_or(df['ABM_0'],mask)).apply(int).apply(bin).str[3:]
df['ABM_1_Bin']=(np.bitwise_or(df['ABM_1'],mask)).apply(int).apply(bin).str[3:]

df['ABM_0_8_11_dec']=(np.bitwise_or(df['ABM_0'],mask)).apply(int).apply(bin).str[3:].str[4:].str[:-8].apply(int, base=2)
df['ABM_0_Bin_8_11']=(np.bitwise_or(df['ABM_0'],mask)).apply(int).apply(bin).str[3:].str[4:].str[:-8]
#To convert to binary of 16 digits
# .str[3:] removes ob1 of the MSB

df
```

## where I get the dataframe as below

```
    ABM_0   ABM_1   ABM_0_Bin   ABM_1_Bin   ABM_0_8_11_dec  ABM_0_Bin_8_11
0   1792    0   0000011100000000    0000000000000000    7   0111
1   512 128 0000001000000000    0000000010000000    2   0010
2   1024    57778   0000010000000000    1110000110110010    4   0100
3   768 65491   0000001100000000    1111111111010011    3   0011
4   1280    6039    0000010100000000    0001011110010111    5   0101
5   1536    9   0000011000000000    0000000000001001    6   0110
6   1792    0   0000011100000000    0000000000000000    7   0111
7   512 129 0000001000000000    0000000010000001    2   0010
8   1024    33550   0000010000000000    1000001100001110    4   0100
9   768 15196   0000001100000000    0011101101011100    3   0011
10  1280    9495    0000010100000000    0010010100010111    5   0101
11  1536    9   0000011000000000    0000000000001001    6   0110
12  1792    0   0000011100000000    0000000000000000    7   0111
13  512 130 0000001000000000    0000000010000010    2   0010
14  1024    8686    0000010000000000    0010000111101110    4   0100
15  768 32768   0000001100000000    1000000000000000    3   0011
16  1280    12855   0000010100000000    0011001000110111    5   0101
17  1536    9   0000011000000000    0000000000001001    6   0110
18  1792    0   0000011100000000    0000000000000000    7   0111
19  512 131 0000001000000000    0000000010000011    2   0010
20  1024    41262   0000010000000000    1010000100101110    4   0100
21  768 14061   0000001100000000    0011011011101101    3   0011
22  1280    14679   0000010100000000    0011100101010111    5   0101
23  1536    9   0000011000000000    0000000000001001    6   0110
```

or as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSIsX.png)

Comment: I  tried in different ways like below but I am not getting a proper dataframe df2=[]
for i in range(len(df)) : 
    if df.loc[i, "ABM_0_8_11_dec"]==4 and df.loc[i+1, "ABM_0_8_11_dec"]==3:
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ABM_0' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_0"]], 
     'ABM_1' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_1"]], 
     'ABM_0_Bin' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_0_Bin"]], 
     'ABM_1_Bin' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_1_Bin"]], 
     'ABM_0_8_11_dec' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_0_8_11_dec"]]})
        df2.append(df1)
df2    but I did not get a proper dataframe

Comment: also as below code df2=[]
for i in range(len(df)) : 
    if df.loc[i, "ABM_0_8_11_dec"]==4 and df.loc[i+1, "ABM_0_8_11_dec"]==3:
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ABM_0' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_0"]], 
     'ABM_1' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_1"]], 
     'ABM_0_Bin' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_0_Bin"]], 
     'ABM_1_Bin' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_1_Bin"]], 
     'ABM_0_8_11_dec' : [df.loc[i, "ABM_0_8_11_dec"]]})
        df2.append(df1)
df2

Comment: You may create your own dataframe if required. Kindly help to check when value in the column "ABM_0_8_11_dec" is 3 and its previous value is 4. Then I would like to take 8 LSB of "ABM_0_8_11_dec" with 4 and combine it with 8 LSB of "ABM_0_8_11_dec" with 3 and put this row in a new dataframe.